# Pyproj DLL load failed while importing _network

Tags: python, conda, pyproj

I'm trying to import geopandas in Python. The pyproj module fails to import, with the following error message:

```
  File ~\.conda\envs\lizard\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_compat.py:9 in <module>
    import pyproj

  File ~\.conda\envs\lizard\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py:49 in <module>
    import pyproj.network

  File ~\.conda\envs\lizard\lib\site-packages\pyproj\network.py:10 in <module>
    from pyproj._network import (  # noqa: F401 pylint: disable=unused-import

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _network: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have installed geopandas with `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`. I've tried to `conda remove` and re-install again, but that does not work. I've tried to reinstall pyproj separately with `pip install pyproj` and `conda install -c conda-forge pyproj` but neither have worked. `conda update` pyproj and geopandas hasn't worked either.

In my environment, pyproj clearly has `network.py`, `_network.cp39-win_amd64.pyd`, and `_network.pyi`, so I'm not sure why the module cannot be found.

ETA: I'm using geopandas 0.10.2 and pyproj 3.3.0.

Comment: Could you please show the installed versions of `geopandas` and `pyproj`? Just type `geopandas.__version__` and `pyproj.__version__` in python interpreter.

Comment: Geopandas 0.10.2 and Pyproj 3.3.0

Comment: There is an [issue on pyproj github](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/770) that looks similar to your experience. There the solution was to install [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0).

Comment: Thanks for this, I've seen this too. I was hoping there would be a more direct solution within Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Had to abandon `conda install` entirely and created a new environment which uses `pip install` to get packages. Followed instructions for `pip install geopandas` and now it's working.